# Basic 301 Redirect code not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My pages are not redirecting for some reason. I'm trying to use the below code in my htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3-$4.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3.html

# 301 --- http://www.domain.com/music-classes-san-diego-ca.html => http://www.domain.com/music-classes-in-san-diego-ca.html
RewriteRule ^music-classes-san-diego-ca\.html$ /music-classes-in-san-diego-ca.html? [L,R=301]
```

The 301 redirect is what I'm trying to get to work. It's not redirecting for me. I've also tried this:

```
redirect 301 music-classes-san-diego-ca.html http://www.domain.com/music-classes-in-san-diego-ca.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you are using wordpress, those rules always needs to go last because it routes everything to index.php. Try your rules before wordpress rules. FYI, I personally would use Rewrite for all 301's and not mix them with `RedirectMatch`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^music-classes-san-diego-ca\.html$ /music-classes-in-san-diego-ca.html? [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3-$4.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3.html

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: done! :) I have one other question that ties to the htaccess code.  `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3-$4.html  
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3.html`  

The above code redirects music-classes-dallas-tx to music-classes-in-dallas-tx, and it also moves music-classes-texas to music-classes-texas. It covers city and state. I can't figure out how to get it to work with cities that have two words, for example, San Antonio. What would the redirectmatch code be for that? is that even possible?

Comment: I would use the 3 capture group as any character so it can get two words. I would do something like this `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(.+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3-$4.html` This should match something like `music-classes-in-san-antonio-tx.html`

Comment: thanks - for some reason it's doing a redirect loop and the url looks like this domain.com/music-classes-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-san-antonio-tx.html

Comment: @user1858780 I would to look more into what you want to match more but you should open that particular issue about having a space in a new question. You'll get an answer for that.

Comment: @user1858780 however my tests show's it works for me. I used RewriteRule